# autocomplete ajax net core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-2.0

Autocomplete on the web page doesn't work. There is no displayed suggestion in the input. I'm not familiar with ajax. Thanks in advance for your help.

The Json response looks fine:

```
https://localhost:44333/Cars/SearchProduct?term=for

            0   
            id  1
            label   "ford"
        name    "ProductNameID"
```

the Action looks fine

```
        public ActionResult SearchProduct(string term)//I think that the id that you are passing here needs to be the search term. You may not have to change anything here, but you do in the $.ajax() call
                {

                    var routeList = _context.Product.Where(r => r.ProductName.Contains(term))//this is a text filter no?
                                      .Select(r => new { id = r.ProductID, label = r.ProductName, name = "ProductNameID" }).ToArray();
                    return Json(routeList);
                }
```

And the codde i am using on my webpage

```
     <div class="ui-widget">
            <label>Product test: </label>
            <input id="ProductNameID" name="ProductNameID" type="text" />
        </div>

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#ProductNameID").autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '/Cars/SearchProduct',
                            type: 'GET',
                            cache: false,
                            data: request,
                            dataType: 'json',
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item,
                                        value: item + ""
                                    }
                                }))
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    minLength: 2,
                    select: function (event, ui) {
                        alert('you have selected ' + ui.item.label + ' ID: ' + ui.item.value);
                        $('#ProductNameID').val(ui.item.label);
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your Action is returning id, label and name. I'm thinking that you need to return value too. ie.

```
.Select(r => new { id = r.ProductID, label = r.ProductName, name = 
"ProductNameID",value="Value Column or whatever your calling this" }).ToArray();
```